# How to get element by text with pyquery?

Tags: python, pyquery

I'm writting a spider, and I want to know which link is mean "next page",so I need to get the element by the value = "next page", and then get the link.
It's not only include one tag, it's a whole html source code, and I want to get the specific link.

if I want to get a element like

```
`<a href="http://*****">..</a>`
```

I can use

```
`'a[href^="http"]'`
```

And I try

```
`'a[text="value"]'`
```

Comment: I want the link , but only thing I know is the value of the link

Answer (score 5):

Try 'Contains':

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

doc = pq("<html><body><a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>Next page</a><p>...Next time...</p></body></html>")

el = doc('a:Contains("Next")')
el.text()         # 'Next page'
el.attr['href']   # 'https://stackoverflow.com'
```